# Vim related questions should be asked @ Unix or @ stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, stackexchange

On the one hand VIM is something very UNIXish, on the other it exists also in windows and it's very related to programming. So where is the appropriate place to ask such questions?

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on the nature of your question.  For example, if you want to know how to alter the configuration to enable or modify C++ syntax highlighting in vim, then SO is probably a good place for that.  But if you want to know how to find the Fedora RPMs for the packages your need for that, then unix.SE is probably best.  In other words: is the question a programming-related task, or a *nix sysadmin-related task?